# is there a way to find who is hosting a DNS zone?

Tags: domain-name-system

i'm helping a friend with a consulting job for a small business. they have two offices each with a DSL router and a public IP on the outside. we moved the 2003 SBS server and the email is not working. The DNS on the server is only for AD. I found the zone using some free tools, but i'm trying to figure out who the host is.

other than googling the IP's of the name servers is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may use dig for that:

```
$ dig zone ns
```

or may be other domain lookup like nslookup, host ...

After that you get DNS servers (primary and secondary (ies)) you can look at them on a whois database with tools like whois, and of course if there are listed on these database you will get full information about who host your zone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out who hosts the DNS? If so, check out this quick tool, it will help you find DNS entries based on IP and domain name. http://www.zoneedit.com/lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

refer to :-http://www.easywhois.com/index.php?mode=dnsinfo&domain= there when you will enter your domain name you will get all the information you need regarding DNS of your domain.